# How to parse gujarati date and formate in predefined formate

Tags: android, android-studio, date, datetime

I want to parse date like "21 એપ્રિલ, 2121" and want to final output like "21-04-2121".
but i get error in parsing gujarati date.
please help me if anyone do like this.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following function to parse date. And pass `inputDateFormat` according to your input:

```
public static String parseStringDate(String dateToConvert, String inputDateFormat) {
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputDateFormat, new Locale("guj"));
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateToConvert);
        return outputFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        return dateToConvert;
    }
}
```

Remember here input date's local (`dateToConvert`'s locale) will be Gujarati.

You can move locale to function parameter and for `inputDateFormat` you must have to pass. Even if it from server side it is predefined, you can ask to server person.

For any other language you can change the language code in `Locale` parameter:

```
public static String parseStringDate(String dateToConvert, String inputDateFormat, Locale locale) {
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputDateFormat, locale); // new Locale("guj")
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Date date = inputFormat.parse(dateToConvert);
        return outputFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        return dateToConvert;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. Your solution working. can you help me for case that use same function for all language then what changes i have to do?. input date format also don't know beacuse it comes from service